# Matplotlib figure appears in notebook but not in native python

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

I just installed Tensorflow 2 on my PC and attempted to implement the example found in this colab => [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l04c01_image_classification_with_cnns.ipynb).

The whole thing appeared to work - except that the final matplotylib figure did not appear (The first two appeared fine, but never the third).

I then tried running exactly the same code in a jupyter notebook (with the addition of `%matplotlib inline` at the start) and then I would see all three figures.

Full code below:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

# Import TensorFlow and TensorFlow Datasets
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
tfds.disable_progress_bar()

# Helper libraries
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(tf.__version__)

import logging
logger = tf.get_logger()
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

dataset, metadata = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', as_supervised=True, with_info=True)
train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset['train'], dataset['test']

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal',      'Shirt',   'Sneaker',  'Bag',   'Ankle boot']

num_train_examples = metadata.splits['train'].num_examples
num_test_examples = metadata.splits['test'].num_examples
print("Number of training examples: {}".format(num_train_examples))
print("Number of test examples:     {}".format(num_test_examples))

def normalize(images, labels):
  images = tf.cast(images, tf.float32)
  images /= 255
  return images, labels

# The map function applies the normalize function to each element in the train
# and test datasets
train_dataset =  train_dataset.map(normalize)
test_dataset  =  test_dataset.map(normalize)

# view stuff

# Take a single image, and remove the color dimension by reshaping
for image, label in test_dataset.take(1):
  break
image = image.numpy().reshape((28,28))

# Plot the image - voila a piece of fashion clothing
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.colorbar()
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()


plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
i = 0
for (image, label) in test_dataset.take(25):
    image = image.numpy().reshape((28,28))
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[label])
    i += 1
plt.show()

# Setup the layers
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,  activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

# compile the model 
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# train the model

BATCH_SIZE = 32
TRAINING_EPOCHS_TO_USE=1 # 10 in original example

train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat().shuffle(num_train_examples).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=TRAINING_EPOCHS_TO_USE, steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(num_train_examples/BATCH_SIZE))



def plot_image(i, predictions_array, true_labels, images):
  predictions_array, true_label, img = predictions_array[i], true_labels[i], images[i]
  plt.grid(False)
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])

  plt.imshow(img[...,0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)

  predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions_array)
  if predicted_label == true_label:
    color = 'blue'
  else:
    color = 'red'

  plt.xlabel("{} {:2.0f}% ({})".format(class_names[predicted_label],
                                100*np.max(predictions_array),
                                class_names[true_label]),
                                color=color)

def plot_value_array(i, predictions_array, true_label):
  predictions_array, true_label = predictions_array[i], true_label[i]
  plt.grid(False)
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])
  thisplot = plt.bar(range(10), predictions_array, color="#777777")
  plt.ylim([0, 1])
  predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions_array)

  thisplot[predicted_label].set_color('red')
  thisplot[true_label].set_color('blue')



# test the model

test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_dataset, steps=math.ceil(num_test_examples/32))

print('Accuracy on test dataset:', test_accuracy)

for test_images, test_labels in test_dataset.take(1):
  test_images = test_images.numpy()
  test_labels = test_labels.numpy()
  predictions = model.predict(test_images)


i = 0
plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plot_image(i, predictions, test_labels, test_images)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plot_value_array(i, predictions, test_labels)
```

Comment: in native python you have to use `plt.show()` to display it. You forgot `plt.show()` after last plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `plt.show()` at the end of your script.